# Limit change to specific table id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a very simple checkbox input for an html table. I have 3 tables in my page, the problem if I uncheck ".PrenomTCG", it hides all the results (Prenom) in 3 tables.

So, is it possible to assign an id in my jQuery function ? For example "prenomTable"

```js
var $ = jQuery;
// Checkbox
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Prénom TCG
    $('#prenomEpiques').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) 
            $('.prenomEpique').fadeIn('slow');
        else 
            $('.prenomEpique').fadeOut('slow');
    });
  $('#prenomEpiques').change();    
    // Prénom TCG
    $('#prenomTCG').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) 
            $('.prenomTCG').fadeIn('slow');
        else 
            $('.prenomTCG').fadeOut('slow');
    });
  $('#prenomTCG').change();       
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" id="prenomEpiques" class="input_checkbox" checked>When unchecked, I want to hide only rows in the <b>Table 1</b>.
</label><br/>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" id="prenomTCG" class="input_checkbox" checked>When unchecked, I want to hide only rows in the <b>Table 2</b>.
</label>
<h1>Table 1</h1>
<table id="tableauPrenoms1">
   <thead>
      <tr id="header">
         <th>Nom</th>
         <th>Prénom</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="prenomTCG">
         <td>Jean</td>
         <td>Pierre</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="prenomEpique">
         <td>Michel</td>
         <td>Francis</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<h1>Table 2</h1>
<table id="tableauPrenoms2">
   <thead>
      <tr id="header">
         <th>Nom</th>
         <th>Prénom</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="prenomTCG">
         <td>Françoise</td>
         <td>Léa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="prenomEpique">
         <td>Helene</td>
         <td>Marie</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show the issue via fiddler?

Comment: Post the HTML structure.

Comment: Added to the post, sorry

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do

Comment: @Bdloul I updated the JSFiddle, I hope it's more understandable

Comment: if you want to hide .prenomEpique only in a specific tab, you can use sonethiung like that  $('#tableauPrenoms1 .prenomEpique') instead of $('. $('.prenomEpique')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a more specific selector, `#tableauPrenoms1 .prenomEpique`.

```js
var $ = jQuery;
// Checkbox
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Prénom TCG
  $('#prenomEpiques').change(function() {
    if (this.checked)
      $('#tableauPrenoms1 .prenomEpique').fadeIn('slow');
    else
      $('#tableauPrenoms1 .prenomEpique').fadeOut('slow');
  });
  $('#prenomEpiques').change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" id="prenomEpiques" class="input_checkbox" checked>When unchecked, I want to hide only rows in the Table 1.
</label>
<h1>Table 1</h1>
<table id="tableauPrenoms1">
  <thead>
    <tr id="header">
      <th>Nom</th>
      <th>Prénom</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="">
      <td>Jean</td>
      <td>Pierre</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="prenomEpique">
      <td>Michel</td>
      <td>Francis</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<h1>Table 2</h1>
<table id="tableauPrenoms2">
  <thead>
    <tr id="header">
      <th>Nom</th>
      <th>Prénom</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="">
      <td>Françoise</td>
      <td>Léa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="prenomEpique">
      <td>Helene</td>
      <td>Marie</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Okay, it was very easy. Sorry for this dumb question :s